# Too many values to unpacked Error for nuested for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using nested for loop to compute the distance for around 20 points using the following script:

```
df = pd.read_csv('LOC.txt',sep='\t',header=None)
lat=df[0]*((22/7)/180)
lon=df[1]*((22/7)/180)
R=6371
dis=[]
lat1 = 33.17*(22/7)/180
lon1 = 73.98*(22/7)/180

for lat2, lon2 in [df[0], df[1]]:
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    u = R * c
    dis.append(float(u))
df_hr = pd.DataFrame(dis)
print(df_hr)
```

But, it gives me this error for this line:

> ```
> ---> 14 for lat2, lon2 in [df[0], df[1]]:
> ```
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

May someone suggests to me how I can solve this

Comment: Add more traceback on which line you're getting this error.

Comment: ---> 14 for lat2, lon2 in [df[0], df[1]]:

Comment: Sounds like you have invalid lines in loc.txt (lines that have only a single value where two are expected)

Comment: I have carefully check my data every line has two data points

Comment: `print(df.shape, df[0], df[1])`; add a few lines from LOC.txt so that your issue can be reproduced

Comment: I don't think you should be iterating here at all; numpy as vectorized versions of functions like [sin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html) which work well with pandas Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate two items in a list at same time with `in` operator directly. This is expected,

```
---> 14 for lat2, lon2 in [df[0], df[1]]:
```

**Use this way to iterate two items in a list at the same time,**

```
li = ["a", "b"]

for a, b in zip(*[iter(li)]*2):
    print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
a b
```

**For your case,**

```
df = pd.read_csv('LOC.txt',sep='\t',header=None)
lat=df[0]*((22/7)/180)
lon=df[1]*((22/7)/180)
R=6371
dis=[]
lat1 = 33.17*(22/7)/180
lon1 = 73.98*(22/7)/180
location = [df[0], df[1]]
for lat2, lon2 in zip(*[iter(location)]*2):
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    u = R * c
    dis.append(float(u))
df_hr = pd.DataFrame(dis)
print(df_hr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I finally find a way to solve this:

Here is the script for someone's else reference:

```
df = pd.read_csv('LOC.txt',sep='\t',header=None)
lat=df[0]*((22/7)/180)
lon=df[1]*((22/7)/180)
R=6371
dis=[]
lat1 = 33.17*(22/7)/180
lon1 = 73.98*(22/7)/180

for lat2, lon2 in zip (df[0]*(22/7)/180, df[1]*(22/7)/180):
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    u = R * c
    dis.append(float(u))
df_hr = pd.DataFrame(dis)
print(df_hr)
```